# Review Orchards Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I'm looking for a base project which I could extensible and quickly deploy for small project such as company website, small shop, blog.... I've used Orchards http://orchardproject.net, but it's too sophiscated to understand internal process and customize.

Could you please review pros and cons of Orchard, or recommend me others that simplier.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Orchard CMS is like a small laboratory for future ideas but it's quite hard to work with for real projects despite having some very good core ideas.

Pro:

- ASP MVC with Razor view engine
- Modules
- Good documentation for a open-source project

Con:

- Lack of automated generated admin UI (you write the back and front-end UI)
- Lack or improper hierarchical data structures and 1:N/N:N relations
- Too big and complex for small projects it trying to address

You may try Umbraco or just write a new ASP MVC application with a library of custom controls.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with all the cons. For admin UI basically you write only piece of code that displays the edit form. 1-N/N-N data structures are perfectly supported - http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations.ashx). Umbraco is bigger than Orchard, but it as for now I'm pretty sure it has a greater library of modules though. But in this rather simple and standard project I'd consider using Orchard, as basic modules (blogs, pages and such) are here. Writing from scratch would be reinventing the wheel...

Comment: I forgot about the documentation which is quite good.

Comment: I'm using orchard on a collection of sites now. It is improving quite a lot with the new releases, but yes it is still too difficult to understand. I really can't grasp what's going on.

Comment: I've been using Orchard for two weeks now, and I'm finding it very difficult.  Tasks that would be trivial in Asp.Net MVC involve hours of research to understand all the levels of abstraction and non-standard conventions Orchard uses.  Getting a simple site up and running is easy in Orchard, but so far I'm wishing we would have just used regular MVC for our slightly more complicated site.

Comment: Taking the time to get to know Orchard has been a great investment for me.  The flexibility of the system is worth getting over the hump.  Also, none of the complexity is unnecessary when you really look into it.

Comment: I hope some serious efforts get made to make it easier to learn, because otherwise I can see the whole thing getting dumped in a year or two which would be a shame.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at both Orchard and N2 CMS and I would say that if you're developer and want a CMS that provides simplicity whilst allowing you to create quite complex sites then N2 is the CMS for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Orchard for developing some sites.

I love it.

It is not so easy to understand at first because there are so many little pieces to understand.

But after some time when the big (and the small) picture is more clear, you will appreciate the fact that you have to code (or just get from gallery and install) the little functionality you need.

If you need send an email, you use the corresponding module, and you never need to code yours or you can replace sending feature with a new one and it is available to all other modules.

Base framework includes some useful functions like db-layer, authentication e, indeeded, every other module you may install...

Have fun!